# MingW GCC sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in #include <jni.h>

Tags: gcc, java-native-interface

I am trying to compile a C program which uses Java's [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) header `jni.h`, but I am getting the following error:

```
sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in #include <jni.h>
```

I am using the 64 bit JDK, so I don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 4):

The problem turned out to be that I was using the 32-bit version of MinGW GCC. On updating to the 64-bit compilers, the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

you should download a 64bit mingw version at https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/

download the exe installer